# Selecting greatest value in an array, MIPS assembly

Tags: mips

Hi I made an MIPS assembly code to print the greatest value of an array but it isn't work correctly.

Instead, it is always printing the latest value in the array. Here is the code:

I expect that when `$a0` (greatest value) it is smaller than `$a1` (current vector element) `$a3` it is set to true, so `bgtz $a3,if` evaluates to true and the execution is branched to `if`, where the array value it is copied to `$a0`. Otherwise, when `$a0` would be bigger than `$a1`, `$a3` is
set to `0`, so `bgtz $a3,if` evaluates to false, so it executes the jump instruction following it, that has the purpose of executing the rest of the code without loading `$a1` value into `$a0`. The problem it is that the jump instruction doesn't seem to be executed since it is loading `$a1` value into `$a0` in each loop iteration. What I am doing wrongly?

```
.text
.globl main
main:
   li $a0,0
   la $a1,$vector
   li $a2,4
   jal maior                       # maior
   li $v0,1                        # imprime o resultado
   syscall
   li $v0,10                       # termina
   syscall
maior:
   subu $sp,$sp,8                  # Abre um espaco na pilha
loop:
   subu $a2,$a2,1
   slt  $a3,$a0,$a1
   bgtz $a3,if
   j    else
if:
   lw   $a0,0($a1)
else:
   addu $a1,$a1,4
   bgtz $a2,loop
   addu $sp,$sp,8                # retira o espaco ocupado na pilha
   jr $ra
.data
$vector: .word 26, 21, 22, 24`
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you say that `$a1` contains the current vector element when it actually contains the current vector address.

To change this, I introduce a load from `$a1` into `$t0` as so:

```
.text
.globl main
main:
   li $a0,0
   la $a1,$vector
   li $a2,4
   jal maior                       # maior
   li $v0,1                        # imprime o resultado
   syscall
   li $v0,10                       # termina
   syscall
maior:
   subu $sp,$sp,8                  # Abre um espaco na pilha
loop:
   subu $a2,$a2,1
   lw   $t0,0($a1)
   slt  $a3,$a0,$t0
   bgtz $a3,if
   j    else
if:
   move $a0,$t0
else:
   addu $a1,$a1,4
   bgtz $a2,loop
   addu $sp,$sp,8                # retira o espaco ocupado na pilha
   jr $ra
.data
$vector: .word 21, 26, 22, 24
```

Comment: I tested the cody and the problem didn't go away, it keeps showing the last value of the array

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. It works on my end. I have included the full code above just in case there was some ambiguity.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to change the $a1 to $t0 in the slt instruction. I have a doubt about this code. Why I can't use lw $a, 0 (t0) instead move $a0, $t0 ?

Comment: `lw` loads from memory at the location pointed to by `$t0` whereas `move` moves the content of `$t0` to `$a0`. There are very different.

Comment: So when I do lw $a0, 0($t0), it is taking the value stored at $t0 ( which should 21... 24), add zero to it, as if these values were a real memory adress and then dereference it? That would explain the error message that I receive when trying to use lw in place of move, as it is trying to acess a protected memory region.

Comment: Correct. `lw` loads from memory given an address. Also, if the solution works for you, please mark it as accepted.